# Reading/accessing stackedwidgets child widget's parameters through objectName

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have a few layouts. Amongst them, one houses the Page buttons, while another constitutes stackedWidget. I was able to dynamically add new Page buttons and new pages in the stackedwidget through `add_command` function. Each new stackedWidget pages has a dynamically added label and them given objectName as well.

How to access(read) the objects in the dynamically added pages and labels through objectName? New Pages, which were also given objectName were only accessible through setCurrentIndex(index) instead of setCurrentWidget(objectName). The reason being is that I want to upload the values later into a database. Code shared here is an MWE.

For example, reading the `lblPage2` which were dynamically added in the `display` function, returns AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'lblPage2'. Did you mean: 'lblPage1'?
```

Similarly, showing newly added stackedWidget pages though objectName, e.g. `page2` returns a similar error (only accessible through index). I have a guess that these errors are due to the objects weren't initialized when the main class was called.

How to access/read the dynamically added objects through objectName? Or should there be a second init?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(277, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.btnPage1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnPage1.setObjectName("btnPage1")
        self.btnPage1.setText("Page 1")
        self.btnPage1.clicked.connect(lambda i=0 :self.display(i))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btnPage1)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page1.setObjectName("page1")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page1)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.lblPage1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page1)
        self.lblPage1.setObjectName("lblPage1")
        self.lblPage1.setText("This is Page 1")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.lblPage1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.btnAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnAdd.setObjectName("btnAdd")
        self.btnAdd.setText("Add")
        self.btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.add_command)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btnAdd)
        self.btnRemove = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnRemove.setObjectName("btnRemove")
        self.btnRemove.setText("Remove")
        self.btnRemove.clicked.connect(self.remove_command)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btnRemove)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def add_command(self):
        #add new page button
        btn_count = self.stackedWidget.count()
        new_btn_count = str(btn_count + 1)
        new_btn_text = str(new_btn_count)
        new_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        new_btn.setText("Page{0}".format(new_btn_text))
        new_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display(btn_count))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(new_btn)

        #add new page
        new_page_count = str(btn_count + 1)
        new_page_text = str(new_btn_count)
        new_page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        new_page.setObjectName("page{0}".format(new_page_text))
        self.new_verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(new_page)
        new_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(new_page)
        new_lbl.setObjectName("lblPage{0}".format(new_page_text))
        new_lbl.setText("This is Page {0}".format(new_page_text))
        self.new_verticalLayout.addWidget(new_lbl)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(new_page)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(btn_count)
    
        print("Added")


    def remove_command(self):
        #remove page code
        print("Removed")

    def display(self,i):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(i)
        #self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWdiget(Page2) - returns error

        print(self.lblPage2.text()) #returns error
        #print(self.lblPage3.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why do you specifically need to access the pages through their object name?

Comment: @musicamante to map to table fields/headers of a database. i. e. retrieve data by pages and its contents. in my actual application, there will be several QLineEdits. would be easier if i name them and hence retrieve thier contents and map to database fields. in mwe above, i used a Qlabel for demo/test. that is my thought process, perhaps there are other ways?

Comment: You could technically use [`findChild(classType, objectName)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild), but that's not very practical. An easier way would be to keep a list of the pages, or eventually use a dictionary where keys are the names and values are the pages. Then you could make every child widget an attribute of the page: `new_page.fieldEdit = QLineEdit()`, etc. You could even create a QWidget subclass to do the same (in that case, it would become `self.fieldEdit = QLineEdit()`), then create a new instance and add it to the stacked widget every time.